# How to test or verify check box is selected or not selected by using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to test or verify check box is selected or not selected by using selenium webdriver java

```
    package newpackage; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
    //import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.*;

    public class Qemr { public static void main(String[]args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.3:9091";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    WebElement chkPersist = driver.findElement(By.name("remember"));
    chkPersist=click(); 
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        System.out.println("chkPersist.isChecked()"); 
    }    
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

yes there are methods available which you can use for ny kind of controls, for eg. for check box you can use isSelected() method which returns boolean value i.e. 0/1
for your scenario

```
  package newpackage; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Qemr {
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      String baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.3:9091";
      driver.get(baseUrl);
      WebElement chkPersist = driver.findElement(By.name("remember"));
     //chkPersist.click();
     if(chkPersist.isSelected())
     {
         System.out.println("Check box is Selected..");
     }

  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question** : How to test or verify check box is selected or not selected by using selenium webdriver java.

**Answer** : Yes we can verify webelement is selected or not using isSelected() method

```
package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Qemr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.3:9091";

        driver.get(baseUrl);

        WebElement chkPersist = driver.findElement(By.name("remember"));

        // Verify chkPersist element is Selected or Not ?

        if (chkPersist.isSelected()) {

            // if chkPersist element is selected then we print message 
            System.out.println("chkPersist element is already selected");


        } else {

            // if chkPersist element is not selected then we select / click on chkPersist element
            chkPersist.click();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElement("").isSelected()` option is there to check whether `Checkbox` is selected. you can find solution in your updated code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*; 
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class StackOverFlow1
{ 
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl="http://192.168.1.3:9091";
        driver.get(baseUrl); 
        boolean chkPersist=driver.findElement(By.name("remember")).isSelected();
        if(chkPersist)
        {
            System.out.println("chkPersist is in selected state");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but the thing is that i have check the checkbox condition is getting true or false on click http://screencast.com/t/DnhsiEai9n1

Comment: Update your code as below, `chkPersist=click();` -->comment it out or remove this line
    `for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        System.out.println("Checkbox is selected:"+chkPersist.isSelected());  -->Updated syso statement
    }`